# How remove list to listbox with Button using MVVM silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, listbox

My Problem, I can't remove list in my listbox from browser, but when i debug in my code data list has removed.

View Model

```
private List<Customer> _listCustomer = new List<Customer>();
    public List<Customers> ListCustomers
    {
        get { return _listCustomers; }
        set { _listCustomers = value; OnPropertyChanged("ListCustomers"); }
    }

    private ICommand _removeCommand; 
    public ICommand RemoveCommand
    {
        get { return _removeCommand ?? (_removeCommand = new RelayCommand(param => ButtonRemoveCustomer(), null)); }
        set { OnPropertyChanged("ListCustomers"); }
    }

private void ButtonRemoveCustomer()
    {
        ListCustomers.Remove(this.SelectCustomer);
        this.SelectCustomer = null;
    }
```

My View

```
<Intersoft:UXListBox x:Name="CustData" Width="200" MaxHeight="500" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectCustomer, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                         ItemsSource="{Binding ListCustomers, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataListTemplate}" 
                                         VerticalScrollBarVisibility ="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>

<Intersoft:UXButton Content="Remove List" Command="{Binding RemoveCommand, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="100"/>
```

How to fix my code ??

Answer (score 0):

```
private void ButtonRemoveCustomer()
{
   ListCustomers.Remove(this.SelectCustomer);
   OnPropertyChanged("ListCustomers");
   this.SelectCustomer=null;
}
```